# Handling logs in multiprocess tornado apps

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, tornado

```
### Start 4 subprocesses ###
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8000)
server.start(4) # 4 subprocesses
 
### Logger using TimeRotatingFileHandler within each app ###
timefilehandler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=os.path.join(dirname, logname + '.log'),
    when='MIDNIGHT',
    interval=1,
    encoding='utf-8'
)
```

Using tornado with mutiple subprocesses and logger resulted in multiple logging files subfixed like(if using file name as logging name):

```
service_0.log
service_1.log
service_2.log
service_3.log
```

Is it possible to enable all the subprocesses to write to one place in tornado? Or if it is better to use some log aggregation tools to handle the hassle since it is quite inconvenient to check the logs one by one, any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no standard way to Log from multiple processes to a single file. The suggested solutions are to send the log entries to a single process which writes to the file via a `QueueHandler`, or set up a server that takes either raw socket connections from `SocketHandler` or http requests via `HTTPHandler`. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: It's not the **exact** description of your situation but I think this should be pretty good advice: [*"Deploying Web applications using Gunicorn and uWSGI"*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#deploying-web-applications-using-gunicorn-and-uwsgi)

Comment: @Aaron thanks, `QueueHandler` is good advice, I'll look into it. We didn't deploy the app behind the wsgi  since we may need some async feature tornado provided.

Comment: The advice given for Gunicorn and uWSGI can be applied to any webserver. It simply explains to use a simple socket server to accept log records from `SocketHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different (sub)processes write to a single file - if you want to solve that you should use a log aggregator where different tornado servers log to a common endpoint (either in the cloud or locally). If you're not inclined to use a third party solution you can write one in Tornado.

Look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html to see if there's anything you like.

Or you can grep 4 files at the same time.

p.s. IIRC using subprocesses is not recommended for production, so I would suggest you run 4 processes with different ports and use the port in the log name as well.